# How can I set ntop not to shorten host names?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, network-monitoring, ntop

With most screens in ntop, there is a list of hosts. Unfortunately, in almost every one, the host name is shorted, for some reason. When the host names follow the company standard, this results in the main identifying section of the hostname disappearing. For instance, if the name is "main_testing_18.tla.domain.org", ntop will display "main...omain.org", which is almost completely useless.

How can this be turned off?